How to set enumerate environment with a font like this?
How should I set up the enumerate environment to achieve the following effect? In particular, I can't find a way to achieve the following font style.


Please add a short, but compilable test file which allows us to reproduce the problem. It should include a class, the necessary packages and a document environment.

You need to 1) identify the two fonts (or find similar ones), 2) read the manual to the enumitem package or some similar package that allows styling lists, 3) stitch together everything. The grey line could just be a vertical rule which you can easily add to the counter.

I have no idea what fonts these are. The sans serif font looks similar to Alegreya Sans with the slanted top of the small letter i. The serif fonts looks more like some kind of Baskerville.
But set aside the question of the exact fonts, you can achieve this using the enumitem package with settings similar to these:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem, xcolor}
\usepackage{AlegreyaSans, Alegreya}

\newcommand{\verticalsep}{%
   \hspace{.75ex}\textcolor{black!25}{\rule[-.25ex]{.8pt}{2ex}}%
}

\newlist{myenumerate}{enumerate}{2}
\setlist[myenumerate]{
    label=\arabic*\verticalsep, 
    font=\sffamily\bfseries,
    labelsep=1.25ex,
    nosep,
    topsep=.75ex,
    itemsep=.75ex,
}
\setlist[myenumerate,2]{
    label=\roman*\verticalsep,
}

\begin{document}

\begin{myenumerate}
    \item This leads to \ldots
    \item this. By the way:
    \begin{myenumerate}
        \item This leads to \ldots
        \item this leads to \ldots
        \item this.
    \end{myenumerate}
    \item Let's proceed \ldots
\end{myenumerate}

\end{document}


